# ¿Cómo logro mostrar un binario de 2 bits, en uno de 8 bits?

Tags: python, binario

Por ejemplo, el binario de 2 es '10', pero me gustaría imprimir '00000010'
Esto lo realice en python y use bin(2)[2:]
pero me gustaría saber como logro imprimir ese número en 8 bits

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! pues sin saber en que lenguaje, y que intentaste, es dificil ayudarte...

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp), puedes usar `zfill`, pero realmente sería bueno que incluyeras un [mcve] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc Me funciono con `zfill`, Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta más simple es usar la función `str.format()` que permite convertir a cadena una variable, y tiene muchas opciones para elegir el formato final deseado.

Por defecto genera el resultado en base 10:

```
num = 2
cadena = "{}".format(num)
# genera cadena = '2'
```

Pero con especificadores que irían dentro de las llaves y tras un signo `:` se puede especificar que salga en binario (especificador `b`) y rellenado con ceros por la izquierda hasta alcanzar una longitud de 8 (anteponiendo `08` a la `b`). Así:

```
num = 2
cadena = "{:08b}".format(num)
# genera cadena = "00000010"
```

Todos los detalles de qué puedes poner dentro de las llaves para diferentes conversiones y formatos están especeificados en el [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

A partir de Python3.6 todo eso puedes hacerlo también con f-strings:

```
cadena = f"{num:08b}"
```

Answer (score 1):

También pudes usar un operador `bitwise`, en este caso `OR`:

```
X1 = 0b100000000 # Constante
t1 = 2
print(bin(X1 | t1)[3:])
```

output:

```
00000010
```

Comment: Buena solución, pero creo que deberías poner el comentario `// Constante` como `# Constante`, que si no parece que estás haciendo una división entera de una constante.

Comment: Cierto, me confundo con C.  Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Con un bucle `while` puedes ir añadiendo ceros al número hasta que llegues al tamaño que quieres:

```py
num = 2
bin_num = bin(num)[2:]
while len(bin_num) < 8:
  bin_num = '0' + bin_num
```

Como dicen en los comentarios, también puedes usar [`zfill`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp):

```
num = 2
bin_num = bin(num)[2:].zfill(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
num = 56  # Numero a convertir.
tamano = 8  # Cantidad de digitos 
binario = ''.join([str(min(2**i & num, 1)) for i in range(tamano-1,-1,-1)])
print(binario)
```

La idea es examinar cada bit de `num`, armando una lista con los ceros y unos que se vayan encontrando.

Para generar la lista de dígitos, usamos un `for i in range(tamano - 1, -1, -1)`. Con eso vamos examinando los dígitos de `num` desde el más significativo al menos. Así la lista de dígitos queda generada en el orden correcto.

Para revisar el bit i-esimo de `num`, usamos la expresión `2**i & num`. Esto nos dará cero si no hay un bit en esa posición, y el valor del bit (algo distinto de cero), si lo hay.

Usamos `min(2**i & num, 1)` para reducir los posibles valores a 0 y 1. Luego convertimos el valor numérico a cadena y lo agregamos a la lista de dígitos en formación.

Una vez armada la lista, juntamos todos sus elementos con `join`.

Eso es todo.